# Obtaining a BeanManager object in WebLogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, cdi

The specification of BeanManager (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html) says that "Java EE components may obtain an instance of BeanManager from JNDI by looking up the name java:comp/BeanManager."

I wrote the following code in Jboss 7 to the static initializer block of a class and it worked as expected:

```
BeanManager beanManager = (BeanManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
```

I tried to do the same in WebLogic 12.1.2.0.0 but I got the following error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: remaining name: comp/BeanManager
at weblogic.j2eeclient.SimpleContext.internalLookup(SimpleContext.java:77)
at weblogic.j2eeclient.SimpleContext.lookup(SimpleContext.java:39)
at weblogic.jndi.SimpleContext.lookup(SimpleContext.java:86)
at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.AbstractURLContext.lookup(AbstractURLContext.java:130)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)...
```

Why doesn't it work in WebLogic?

Update:

If I call `CDI.current()` method I get an `IllegalStateException`, so that also doesn't help.
When I call the `new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager")` method, the `InitialContext` doesn't contain `java:comp` namespace, only a `java:global` namespace.

Comment: Does the JAR that include this class include a `beans.xml`?

Comment: Yes, it does. The application works in JBoss environment. If beans.xml were not on the specified location, it wouldn't work on JBoss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred on a developer edition of WebLogic. After we've installed the Middleware version of it, it worked in both 12.1.2 and 1.2.1.3 versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and looks it is a bug in Weblogic.

"Bug 18026126 - STATIC VARIABLE BEANMANAGER IS NOT WORKING"

SOLUTION

To implement the solution, please execute the following steps:

1. Download and review the readme and pre-requisites for Patch 18026126.
2. Ensure that you have taken a backup of your system before applying the recommended patch.
3. Apply the patch in a test environment.
4. Retest the issue.
5. Migrate the solution as appropriate to other environments.

Below is the BUG description:

STATIC VARIABLE BEANMANAGER IS NOT WORKING

```
 private static BeanManagerBeanTest bmbs =
    (BeanManagerBeanTest)BeanLookupUtil.getCdiBean("beanManagerBeanTest")
```

> ```
> throws lookup exception and if we remove static it's working
> ```

```
 public class BeanLookupUtil {

        public static BeanManager getBeanManager(){
            BeanManager beanManager = null;
            try {
                beanManager = (BeanManager)new
    InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return beanManager;
        }

        public static Object getCdiBean(String name){
            Object obj = null;
            try {
                BeanManager bm = getBeanManager();
                Set<Bean<?>> beanSet = bm.getBeans(name);
                if(!beanSet.isEmpty()){
                    Bean<?> bean = beanSet.iterator().next();
                    CreationalContext<?> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
                    obj = bm.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), ctx);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return obj;
        }

    }

    public class TestCtrl {

        private static BeanManagerBeanTest bmbs =
    (BeanManagerBeanTest)BeanLookupUtil.getCdiBean("beanManagerBeanTest");

        public void beanmanagertest() {
            BeanManager beanManager = null;
            try {
                //BeanManagerBeanTest bmbs =
    (BeanManagerBeanTest)BeanLookupUtil.getCdiBean("beanManagerBeanTest");
                bmbs.sum(10, 10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Lookup Error:", e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible to download this patch without Support identifier?

Comment: Don't think so, but you can get 12.1.3 which might have this included.